# HMS subscribe to topic don't subsribe with error message 907122054

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I have developed an app with the Huawei HMS to receive push notifications.

This is my code:

I call this in my main activity on the onCreate

```
subscribe("myTopic");
```

And this is teh subscribe code:

```
public void subscribe(String topic) {
    try {
        HmsMessaging.getInstance(this).subscribe(topic)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "subscribe Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "subscribe failed1: ret=" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "subscribe failed2: ret=" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

But it always enters the "else" where the task was not successful.

How can I subscribe to the topic?

Comment: hi@Manuel Rodrigues,could you pls provide a full log for us to find out what can be wrong?

Comment: The following is log extraction Method,pls refer: Connect the ADB to the phone and run the following commands: adb logcat-v time > D:\hwpush.log 2. Reproduce the problem scenario. 3. Press Ctrl+C to finish.

Answer (score 0):

[Seems to be](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/push-ErrorEnum4) this error means, that PushKit is not yet initialized and you enable auto initialization.

According to [auto initialization documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-client-dev-0000001050042041-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001078601368__section13546121751811), you can use `HmsMessageService#onNewToken` method to do something with initialized PushKit. So try to subscribe to topic in onNewToken method.

Comment: Do you have any example on how to doe it?

Comment: @ManuelRodrigues, you should just extend HmsMessageService, override  onNewToken method and call your subscribe method in onNewToken method

Answer (score 0):

Error message 907122054 indicates that you are using the Push Kit with auto initialization enabled. [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/error-code-0000001050255690-V5)

The official developer documentation states that the onNewToken() method of the HmsMessageService should be used to get the push token.

HmsMessageService, onNewToken()
[Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/hmsmessageservice-0000001050173839-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001078729906__section814414561477)

[Auto Initialization Documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-client-dev-0000001050042041-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001078601368__section13546121751811)

Here is an example of a class that extends HmsMessageService and overrides the onNewToken() method. [Link](https://medium.com/huawei-developers/integrating-huawei-core-push-kit-90f24c8c5d29)

```
public class MyPushService extends HmsMessageService {
    private static final String TAG = "PushDemoLog";
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        Log.i(TAG, "receive token:" + token);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message);
        Log.i(TAG, "getCollapseKey: " + message.getCollapseKey()
                + "\n getData: " + message.getData()
                + "\n getFrom: " + message.getFrom()
                + "\n getTo: " + message.getTo()
                + "\n getMessageId: " + message.getMessageId()
                + "\n getSendTime: " + message.getSentTime()
                + "\n getMessageType: " + message.getMessageType()
                + "\n getTtl: " + message.getTtl());

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = message.getNotification();
        if (notification != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "\n getImageUrl: " + notification.getImageUrl()
                    + "\n getTitle: " + notification.getTitle()
                    + "\n getTitleLocalizationKey: " + notification.getTitleLocalizationKey()
                    + "\n getTitleLocalizationArgs: " + Arrays.toString(notification.getTitleLocalizationArgs())
                    + "\n getBody: " + notification.getBody()
                    + "\n getBodyLocalizationKey: " + notification.getBodyLocalizationKey()
                    + "\n getBodyLocalizationArgs: " + Arrays.toString(notification.getBodyLocalizationArgs())
                    + "\n getIcon: " + notification.getIcon()
                    + "\n getSound: " + notification.getSound()
                    + "\n getTag: " + notification.getTag()
                    + "\n getColor: " + notification.getColor()
                    + "\n getClickAction: " + notification.getClickAction()
                    + "\n getChannelId: " + notification.getChannelId()
                    + "\n getLink: " + notification.getLink()
                    + "\n getNotifyId: " + notification.getNotifyId());
        }
    }
}
```